# Vector arrows on top of letters? Or a better workaround for Word 2003?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I need to insert vector notations in my documents, Microsoft Word 2003:

[image: vector letter]

It takes some time to hack this into Word by creating an equation `{ EQ \O(a;→)}` where the font size of the arrow → has to be adjusted each time. Time consuming hack.

Today I have got the idea, why not use a font that can show instead of "a" an "a→" (→ above the a). But despite searching a lot I could not find any, so my question is if someone has ever heard of such a font.

And the other part of the question: Maybe you know another work around that would work for Word 2003? (I know that Word 2007 has an equation editor but I am on 2003.)

*Disclaimer: I don't want anybody to do a search for me, but I hope there is somebody who **knows** an answer right away.*

Answer (score 2):

Gosh, finally found a Math Vector Font: http://fontsov.com/font/mathvectorbecker21527.html - even though it is seems not that easy to read when font size is around 11.

[image: vector font compare to word eq]

And stumbled over https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145173/63540 where they show math fonts that have letters with arrows, but seems to be Latex-only.